# how to remove a backslash from a python string

Tags: python-3.x

I know this seems like a duplicate question but unsure why this string seems to not want to ditch its backslash.

I am using python 3.8

example String

```
'"sourceSystem" : \'somethingsomething",'
```

Code I have tried

```
>>> word = '"sourceSystem" : \'somethingsomething",'
>>> word.strip()
>>> word.replace('\\', '')
>>> word.split('\\')
>>> re.sub(r"\\.*", "", word)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
    word='"sourceSystem" : \'somethingsomething",'

    string = word.replace("\\","")

    print(string)


    output : "sourceSystem" : 'somethingsomething",
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
s ='"sourceSystem" : \'somethingsomething",'
s1 = s.translate({ord('\\'): None})
print(s1)

output
"sourceSystem" : 'somethingsomething",
```